# a question on Pixley-Roy topology

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and let $F[X]$ be $\{x\subset X:\text{is finite}\}$ with Pixley-Roy topology.

If $X$ is not discrete, how to prove $F[X]$ is not a [Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)?

Thanks ahead:)

---

Definition of Pixley-Roy topology: Basic neighborhoods of $F\in F[X]$ are the sets
$$[F,V]=\{H\in F[X]; F\subseteq H\subseteq V\}$$
for open sets $V\supseteq F$, see e.g. [here](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v03/tp03111s.pdf).

---

I don't know in the theorem 2.2 why each $Z \cap F_n[X]$ is closed, nowhere dense subspace of $Z$?

Comment: I've added the definition of Pixley-Roy topology to your questions, since this topology is (probably) not very well-known.

Comment: BTW you could check Theorem 2.2 in the paper I linked there.
http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v03/tp03111s.pdf

Comment: O, thank you:) Why each $Z \cap F_n[X]$ is closed, nowhere dense subspace of $Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(explaining the theorem 2.2 in the paper linked by Martin Sleziak)

Let $X$ not be discrete, and $p$ be a limit point.

Put $F_n[X]=\lbrace A\subseteq X\vert \lvert A\rvert\leq n\rbrace$, $Z=[\lbrace p\rbrace,X]$

If $F[Z]$ were Baire, so would $Z$. But $Z=\bigcup_n (Z\cap F_n[X])$, and each of $Z\cap F_n[Z]$ is nowhere dense and closed:

- it is closed because its complement $\bigcup_{\lvert A\rvert >n} (Z\cap[A,X])$ is open.
- it is nowhere dense, because any nonempty basic open subset of $Z$ is of the form $[A,U]$ for $p\in A\subseteq U$, so in particular $U$ is infinite (as a neighbourhood of $p$), so it has an $n+1$-element subset $B$. Then $[A\cup B,U]$ is a subset of $[A,U]$ disjoint from $F_n[X]\cap Z$

Comment: Yeer, thaks tomasz; I got it:)

Comment: I made a slight mistake here: not every open subset of $Z$ is of the form, but every BASIC subset is (so in particular any open subset contains one like this).